# Slow shutdown caused by cryptswap

Tags: shutdown, 15.04, swap, ecryptfs, systemd

After upgrading to 15.04 my computer takes a very long time to power off. Hitting escape during shutdown shows messages like so:

```
(1 of 6) A stop job is running for /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-CRYPT-PLAIN-cryptswap1 (30s / 1min 30s)
```

On the next boot, I've tried looking for these messages all throughout my logs but I can't find them anywhere so I'm having difficulty working out which programs might be responsible. I also can't see any error logs relating to `cryptswap` or `ecryptfs`.

Ideally I'd like to solve the root problem, but I'd settle for being able to drastically reduce the timeout on whatever is waiting for these processes (I'm assuming it's `systemd`, but I don't know where to look to change that setting).

Comment: how many disks do you have involved? (including partitions if using raid) also if you are dual or multi booting it could be affecting things  It looks more like (from the output) that you have some kind of server style services that are running that are taking some time to quit.  Hope suggestion helps...

Comment: Seems cryptswap is slow on 14.04 as well. Swap makes it unbearably slow.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this answer coming more than a year after the question will help some users.
I spent some time on this issue and I finally got a satisfying answer for my configuration.
In short: it is not necessarly cryptswap the culprit but **can be another process hanging and thus blocking cryptswap.**

In my case, my VPN client is not shutting down properly and blocks cryptswap exit.

Here is how to diagnosis that:

- Deactivate cryptswap by following these instructions: https://www.logilab.org/blogentry/29155
- Reboot, Reboot
- Do you still see a stop job running?
- If yes, then it is probably the one blocking cryptswap

Identifying this job is not always easy. I was already suspecting my VPN as I noticed that when rebooting immediately after startup, I had no issue. That was because I was rebooting too quick to allow the VPN startup.
If you have no idea, please look for further help on how to identify that particular process blocking your shutdown.

- Once identified, re-activate cryptswap with sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap
- reboot
- exit the identified process
- shutdown

No stop job ? You found your issue :)

Comment: This saved my day. How do you work around VPN blocking swap?